# How to export admin grid only for selected fields in Magento?

Tags: grid

How to export admin grid only for selected fields in Magento?
I have a field which contains link(pdf download link) in admin grid.
I don't want to export that particular field in Export CSV action.So how can I achieve it ?

I want to remove 'Download PDf' column in export mass action, please see attached snapshot with this comments.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In you grid.php file,where you are adding your column,pass **is_system** parameter as true.
For example,

```
 $this->addColumn('url', array(
          'header'    => 'Download PDF',
          'align'     =>'center',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => null,
          'renderer'      => 'Namespace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image',
          'sortable'    => false,
          'filter' => false,
          'is_system'   => true
      ));
```